# Get count and sum for each ip from mysql table

Tags: mysql

Im been looking into generating an IP ADDRESS REPORT from one table and inserting into another but have yet to succeed or find a resource which will allow me to do so.

My IP table which contains many duplicate ip's and would like a sum(minutes) of minutes and count(name) where for each distinct ip

```
ip                  name    minutes
199.199.199.199     nick    23
199.199.199.200     nick    3
199.199.199.200     bob     34
199.199.199.201     bob     56
199.199.199.201     sue     12
199.199.199.202     sue     45
199.199.199.202     helen   65
199.199.199.202     helen   15
```

My current method is the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT(distinct) as ip FROM `ip.ip_stats`;
```

In my PHP, i add each of the distinct ip addreses into an array

```
$arr = array("199.199.199.199","199.199.199.200","199.199.199.201","199.199.199.202");
```

Once the array is generated i run through each in the array

```
foreach($arr as $ip){
     SQL ="SELECT COUNT(name) as cnt, SUM(minutes) as sum FROM `ip.ip_stats` WHERE ip='$ip'";
     $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO ip.ip_report ( ip, count, sum )   
          VALUES ( $ip, $cnt, $sum ) 
     }
}
```

So after getting the sum and count of each ip in the array i then loop through and insert into the report table.

My main problem is the sheer size and amount of time it take for this to run, I have over ten million rows of data and only does 3-5 per minutes (LARGE TABLE THEN MY EXAMPLE).

Is there a way to use mysql to select the distinct and generate the report? 
is there a way of achieving the following query? using a loop or while?

```
SELECT SUM(minutes), COUNT(name) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT(ip) FROM ip.ip_stats) ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe you are after:

```
SELECT s.ip, s.name, SUM(s.minutes) AS TotalMinutes, COUNT(s.name) AS NameCount
FROM ip_stats s
GROUP BY s.ip, s.name
```

Comment: Thanks Linger, This will work perfectly, i completely forgot about GROUP BY and this is definitely the answer i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ip,
    COUNT(name) as cnt,
    SUM(minutes) as sum
FROM `ip.ip_stats`
GROUP BY ip
;
```